# How to rearrange dataframe with likert variables into frequencies/percentages table in r?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with four likert-like variables with only 4 possible values, like this:

```
       group var1 var2 var3 var4
1      1    4    1    3    1
2      2    1    1    1    1
3      1    1    2    1    3
4      2    1    1    2    1
5      1    2    1    4    1
6      2    4    3    4    4
7      1    1    1    1    1
8      2    4    4    3    4
9      2    2    3    3    1
10     1    4    3    2    1
11     2    2    3    1    1
12     2    1    1    1    1
13     2    3    4    4    4
14     2    4    4    4    4
15     1    1    1    1    2
16     2    3    3    2    3
17     2    4    4    2    1
18     2    2    3    4    1
19     1    1    2    1    1
20     2    3    1    3    3
21     1    1    3    1    4
22     1    4    3    4    3
23     2    1    3    3    2
24     2    1    3    1    4
25     2    2    3    2    4
26     1    1    2    3    1
27     1    3    3    1    2
28     1    4    3    3    1
29     1    2    1    3    2
30     2    4    3    3    3
```

Now want to get per group and per variable the value percentages. The result should look something like this:

```
 group  vars    1   2   3   4
    1   var1    %   %   %   %
    1   var2    %   %   %   %
    1   var3    %   %   %   %
    1   var4    %   %   %   %
    2   var1    %   %   %   %
    2   var2    %   %   %   %
    2   var3    %   %   %   %
    2   var4    %   %   %   %
```

The percentages reflect the relative amount of a values within a group, for one variable. 
I guess this should be possible, but I haven't found an R function yet that can help me. Does anyone know a package or function that could help solve this problem?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve this problem, you need to:

- First reshape the data to tall format (as opposed to wide). Use `melt()` from package `reshape2` to do this.
- Then recast your data in the desired shape, using `cast()`. This will give you a data frame with counts.
- Finally, calculate the row-wise percentages.  You can use `apply()`.

Try this:

```
library(reshape2)

mdat <- melt(dat, id.vars=c("group"), variable.name="vars")
cdat <- dcast(mdat, group + vars ~ value, length)
cdat[, 3:6] <- t(apply(cdat[, 3:6], 1, function(x)x/sum(x)))
cdat
```

The result:

```
  group vars         1          2          3          4
1     1 var1 0.4615385 0.15384615 0.07692308 0.30769231
2     1 var2 0.3846154 0.23076923 0.38461538 0.00000000
3     1 var3 0.4615385 0.07692308 0.30769231 0.15384615
4     1 var4 0.5384615 0.23076923 0.15384615 0.07692308
5     2 var1 0.2941176 0.23529412 0.17647059 0.29411765
6     2 var2 0.2352941 0.00000000 0.52941176 0.23529412
7     2 var3 0.2352941 0.23529412 0.29411765 0.23529412
8     2 var4 0.4117647 0.05882353 0.17647059 0.35294118
```

Comment: I must admit it's and additional question, but do you know a way to add a column with the N's?

Comment: My question was too quick, I found it out myself : N <- apply(cdat[, 3:6], 1, function(x)sum(x)); cdat <- cbind(N,cdat)